# Git doesn't change line-endings after creating .gitattributes file

Tags: git, newline

I'd like to set up git such that it changes all LF endings to CRLF.

I've created a .gitattributes file in my root folder of my repo:

```
* text=auto 
# Have git change every .groovy and .java file to crlf
*.java eol=crlf
*.groovy eol=crlf
```

And when committing a .java file that I know has LF endings I'd expect it to change to CRLF when checking out to a new local branch. But it doesn't. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the issue. I was using Egit, where .gitattributes is not currently supported properly yet.
See [This Link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=342372). Currently unresolved.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to specify "text" before the "eol" attribute; so your example would become the following:

```
* text=auto 
# Have git change every .groovy and .java file to crlf
*.java text eol=crlf
*.groovy text eol=crlf
```

Comment: This did not work I'm afraid. Effectively no difference between your .gitattributes and mine.

Comment: Hmm, try setting _autoclrf_ in the global config instead:

`$ git config --global core.autocrlf true`

Comment: git config is a local change for the repositories on my machine. Even though that would probably work for me, I need to fix this set up for a team project.

Comment: You should be able to run this on your master repo too, provided you can get bash access to it. It seems to work fine on my bare master.